# How to include a file using a relative path?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to include a file located in `front/header/header.php` from a `front/user/login.php` file.

How i can include header.php in login.php ? since it needs to step back from `user` folder and then enter to `header` folder.

i tried :

```
<?php include('/header/header.php'); ?>
<?php include('../header/header.php');?>
<?php include('../../header/header.php');?>
<?php include('header/./header.php');?>
<?php include('header/../header.php');?>
<?php include('front/header/./header.php');?>
<?php include('front/header/../header.php');?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you missed context of including path. Try to use:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../header/header.php';
```

It should helps.

Comment: @hameedHamish please provide more info about "not worked".